# PHP uploaded file exist in TMP name, but in fact its not uploaded

Tags: php, apache

I've uploaded a file in PHP, it is in the array $_FILES, the tmp_name is filled with his name, but in fact the file has not been uploaded, why this happens? if the tmp_name is filled, does that mean that it should have been uploaded? because I even had set the folder to 0777, still can't upload, in the phpinfo(); - everything is on...help please

```
foreach($_FILES as $file)
{

    foreach($file['tmp_name']['new'] as $name) {

        echo '<br />'.$name.'<br />';
        if(is_uploaded_file($name))
        {
            echo '1';
        }
        else
        {
            echo '0'; // shows this
        }
        //$res = move_uploaded_file($name, "/uploads");
        //echo $res;
    }
    exit;
}
//exit;
```

the is_uploaded_file - returns false

```
Array
(
    [name] => Array
        (
            [new] => Array
                (
                    [prikrepit_fajl] => 
                    [prikrepit_fajl1] => 
                    [prikrepit_fajl3] => ava.png
                    [prikrepit_fajl333] => ava.png
                    [prikrepit_fajl55555555] => 
                )

        )

    [type] => Array
        (
            [new] => Array
                (
                    [prikrepit_fajl] => 
                    [prikrepit_fajl1] => 
                    [prikrepit_fajl3] => image/png
                    [prikrepit_fajl333] => image/png
                    [prikrepit_fajl55555555] => 
                )

        )

    [tmp_name] => Array
        (
            [new] => Array
                (
                    [prikrepit_fajl] => 
                    [prikrepit_fajl1] => 
                    [prikrepit_fajl3] => /home/users1/v/vizitka77/tmp/phppOtsIp
                    [prikrepit_fajl333] => /home/users1/v/vizitka77/tmp/phpgY6RQ9
                    [prikrepit_fajl55555555] => 
                )

        )

    [error] => Array
        (
            [new] => Array
                (
                    [prikrepit_fajl] => 4
                    [prikrepit_fajl1] => 4
                    [prikrepit_fajl3] => 0
                    [prikrepit_fajl333] => 0
                    [prikrepit_fajl55555555] => 4
                )

        )

    [size] => Array
        (
            [new] => Array
                (
                    [prikrepit_fajl] => 0
                    [prikrepit_fajl1] => 0
                    [prikrepit_fajl3] => 25352
                    [prikrepit_fajl333] => 25352
                    [prikrepit_fajl55555555] => 0
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Show us the code what you tried.

Comment: Why are you saying it wasn't uploaded? Did you actually check the upload folder or did something else happen and you are assuming that it didn't upload? Post all the code and any error message or log file entries that show that the file was not uploaded.

Comment: the is_uploaded_file - return false, I pass the tmp_name to it

Comment: @Divakarcool updated

Comment: @Yash updated code

Comment: @ryantxr update dcode

Comment: @BlurryScript why used nested foreach loop. is there same name of multiple image ..?

Comment: @Yash its an array of tmp_names, some of them are filled, but the the thing is that it returns 0 anyway, the move_uploaded_file also will not work, all the folders are 0777(thus writtable)

Comment: @BlurryScript show your array value also.

Comment: @Yash added array values, those filled are the uploaded files, as you see they are there, but in fact when I check it with is_uploaded_file - it returns false

Comment: Are you uploading one file or multiple?

Comment: @ryantxr as you see from my array, there are multiple files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One important thing to point out: if you don't save the uploaded file during the request, PHP deletes it when the request terminates so the file will be gone.

Second, you are looping over the array incorrectly.  You should try a for loop instead:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($_FILES['new']['tmp_name']); ++$i) {
    $name = $_FILES['new']['name'][$i];
    $path = $_FILES['new']['tmp_name'][$i];
    $err  = $_FILES['new']['error'][$i];

    if ($err != UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        // check error code
        // report error
        continue;
    }

    if (is_uploaded_file($path)) {
        // do something with the file
    }
}
```

EDIT:  In your commented code, `move_uploaded_file($name, "/uploads");` is not the correct syntax for moving the file.

It should look more like:

```
move_uploaded_file($path, "uploads/{$name}");
```

Note: The above is dangerous if you haven't checked the file content and extension.  Be very careful not to allow file uploads with a .php or other executable extension.

Comment: of course I'am saving it during the request, i guess that is the only way i can save it)

Comment: is_uploaded_file was returning false because the wrong value was being passed to it.  In your output, 3 of the files have the error `UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE` meaning no file was passed to the input. @BlurryScript See my last edit too.

Comment: yeah I've checked the UPLOAD_ERR_OK - it is zero....even tough I've added the /uploads/{$name} - it doesn't work, the folders are 0777(writable), no errors, my guess is that based on is_file_uploaded - returns false, so looks like there are no uploaded file in the tmp folder...it is also 0777...what I'am doing wrong?

Comment: `$name` is assumed to be `$_FILES['new']['name'][$i];` from my example above.  Can you update your question with the code you have now so I know what you're working with?  Part of the problem might be that the destination directory in `move_uploaded_file` should be an absolute or relative path.  `/uploads` is not the correct path.

Comment: holy code.....the $_FILES array some how was altered by the umi cms, I don't knwo what the heck it was, but I just changed the default names of the input html files, and it worked...

Comment: Aww that's annoying, I don't like when things like that change the structure of standard PHP globals.  Good find, glad you worked it out!

Answer (score 0):

You should read this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-uploaded-file.php

And this: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php

Looks like you are accessing $_FILES incorrectly.

```
foreach($_FILES['tmp_name']['new'] as $inputName => $file)
{
    // $inputName is the name attribute from the HTML form
    echo '<br />'.$file.'<br />';
    if( is_uploaded_file($file) )
    {
        echo '1';
    }
    else
    {
        echo '0';
    }
    //$file = umiImageFile::upload('uploads',$name,'uploads','new');
    //$res = move_uploaded_file($name, "/uploads");
    //echo $res;
}
```

Comment: there is not such thing as $file['upload_file_name']

Comment: My bad. I wasn't paying attention to the unnecessary inner loop.

Comment: Based on your array output, this should do it.